# on mobile view , my website content intersect with each other when I zoom in on firefox(android) and on safari(ios) but not on chrome(android)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my website view on mobile phones.When I try google chrome(on android) works fine and when I zoom is fine also,however on safari (ios) and mozilla firefox(android) it opens fine but when I zoom in every thing intersect with each other and I don't know what to do I did alot of solutions but didn't work with me .
this is my website http://www.aapgsuez.net

---

```css
@font-face{font-family:'Lato';src:url('fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:'Lato';src:url('fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight:Bold;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:'Lato-Black';src:url('fonts/Lato-Black.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:'Source-Pro';src:url('fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:'Distant_Stroke';src:url('fonts/Distant_Stroke.otf') format('truetype');font-weight:Bold;font-style:normal}@font-face{font-family:'Source-Pro';src:url('fonts/SourceSansPro-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight:normal;font-style:italic}body,ul{margin:0;padding:0}.clearfix::after{content:"";height:0;display:block;clear:both}@media (max-width:900px){nav#side-nav{width:100%;background-color:#C01616}nav#side-nav header{padding:50px;border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2)}nav#side-nav header a.logo{display:block;width:200px;margin:0 auto;}nav#side-nav header a.logo img{width:100%;height:100%}nav#side-nav ul.main-menu{list-style:none}nav#side-nav ul.main-menu li{float:left}nav#side-nav ul.main-menu li a{display:block;padding:20px 30px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none}nav#side-nav ul.main-menu li a:hover{color:#b20c0c;background:#fff}}@media (min-width:900px){nav#side-nav{width:300px;height:100%;overflow-y:overlay;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;background-color:#C01616}nav#side-nav ul.social{position:absolute;left:0;bottom:15px;width:100%;list-style:none;text-align:center}nav#side-nav ul.social li{display:inline-block}nav#side-nav ul.social li a.social-icon{display:block;width:30px;height:30px;background:#fff}nav#side-nav header{padding:50px}nav#side-nav header a.logo{display:block}nav#side-nav header a.logo img{width:100%;height:100%}nav#side-nav ul.main-menu{list-style:none}nav#side-nav ul.main-menu li a{height:50px;color:#fff;font-family:"Source-Pro";text-decoration:none;text-align:center;line-height:50px;font-size:18px;display:block}nav#side-nav ul.main-menu li a.active,nav#side-nav ul.main-menu li a:hover{background:#fff;color:#C01616}}@media (max-width:900px){section#main-content{width:100%}}@media (min-width:900px){section#main-content{width:calc(100% - 300px)}}section#main-content img{width:100%}section#main-content article{padding:20px 5%;margin:0 auto}section#main-content article h1{color:#b20c0c;font-family:"Lato-Black";font-size:30px}section#main-content article h2{margin-top:15px;color:#808080;font-family:"Lato";font-weight:bold;font-size:18px}section#main-content article p{color:#828282;margin-top:20px;font-family:"Lato";font-weight:normal;text-align:justify;font-size:18px}section#main-content article h3{font-size:15px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>About AAPG</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
  <meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes">

  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo2.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script-min.js"></script>
  <style>
a:link    {text-decoration:none;color:#fff;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none;color:#fff;}
a:hover   {text-decoration:none;}
a:active  {text-decoration:none}
</style>
<style>
#all-sponsor{
    padding-top:70px;
    min-height:210px;
    background-image: url('img/14.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
#main-sponsor{
float:left;
width:170px;
}
#technical-sponsor{
float:left;
width: calc(100% - 170px);
}
.s1{
    float:left;
    margin: 7px;
    height:50px;
}


</style>

<style>
    .hvr-bounce-to-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-bottom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000000;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-bottom:hover, .hvr-bounce-to-bottom:focus, .hvr-bounce-to-bottom:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-bottom:hover:before, .hvr-bounce-to-bottom:focus:before, .hvr-bounce-to-bottom:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
    </style>
    <style>
    .container{
      min-height: 100%;
      width:calc(100% -300px) ;
      display: block;
      }    
    .issue1{
      border: 2px solid #808080;
        border-radius:30px;
        padding:20px;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:30px;
        width:calc(100% -300px) ;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .issue2{
      border: 2px solid #808080;
        border-radius:30px;
        padding:20px;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:30px;
        width:calc(100% -300px) ;
        margin: 25px auto;
    }
    .title{
        position:absolute;
        top:-10px;
        margin-left:3px;
        background-color:white;
    }
    
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>

  <nav id="side-nav">
    <header>
      <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="img/logo_white.png" alt="AAPG Suez"></a>
    </header>


    <ul class="main-menu" >
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="past events.html">Past Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="Scientific Articles and Research.html">Scientific Articles and Research</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="social">
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/AAPGSCUSC?fref=ts" target="_blank" class="social-icon fb"><img src="img/Facebook alt 1-1.jpg"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/aapgsusc" target="_blank" class="social-icon tw"><img src="img/Twitter alt 4-1.jpg"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=AAIAABlcbdgBZ8irrSV1g5xLxJFBZl7W2P9MxEo&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile_pic" target="_blank" class="social-icon gm"><img src="img/LinkedIn-Ico.jpg"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://instagram.com/aapgscusc/" target="_blank" class="social-icon in"><img src="img/Instagram-1.jpg"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChi2rpa5uQps2bznDLXlBPg" target="_blank" class="social-icon yt"><img src="img/YTico.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="main-content">
    <img src="img/banner_website.jpg" alt="" class="article">
    <article>
      <h1>About AAPG</h1><br><br>
      
      <div class="container">

      <div id="issue11"><div class="issue1">
        <div style="font-family:Trebuchet MS;color:#000000;font-size:20px" class="title">AAPG SUEZ</div>
        <div style="font-family:Trebuchet MS">
              From our full belief of working in AAPG and from the explosion of AAPG SU SC which started by “Lead, inspire, make a   difference”. And we really did it, until everybody here can finally “Unleash the leader inside”, We continued with more and more spirit and effort, from better to better and last year we really could “Triple ourselves” And now the time is ours, it’s a new start to transform from being better to be the best Now, “The peak is ours”.
              </div><br>
              <div class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" style="border:2px solid #fff;color:#fff;background-color:#a0a0a0;padding:10px 20px;text-align:center;font-family:Trebuchet MS">
              <a href="suez.html" >LEARN MORE</a>
              </div>
      </div></div>
      <div id="issue22"><div class="issue2">
        <div style="font-family:Trebuchet MS;color:#000000;font-size:20px" class="title">AAPG INTERNATIONAL</div>
        <div style="font-family:Trebuchet MS">
              AAPG, an international geological organization, has offices in London, Dubai, Singapore, Bogotá, Lagos and Washington, DC. Included among its membership are geologists, geophysicists, CEOs, managers, consultants, students, and professors.
              </div><br>
              <div class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom" style="border:2px solid #fff;color:#fff;background-color:#a0a0a0;padding:10px 20px;text-align:center;font-family:Trebuchet MS">
              <a href="international.html">LEARN MORE</a>
              </div>
      </div></div>
      
      </div>

    </article>

  
        <footer id="all-sponsor">
            <div id="main-sponsor">
                <h1 style="font-size:20px;color:#b20c0c;font-family:Lato-Black;margin-left:30px">Main Sponsor</h1>
                <div style="padding:20px 0px 10px 20px">
                    <img src="img/apache.png" style="float:left;width:100px;height:40px;margin:10px 0 0 10px">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="technical-sponsor">
                <h1 style="font-size:20px;color:#b20c0c;font-family:Lato-Black;margin-left:30px">Academic Sponsors</h1>

                <div style="padding:20px 0px 10px 20px">

                    <div class="s1">
                        <img src="img/12.png" style="float:left;width:30px;height:30px;margin-top:10px">
                        <h4 style="font-family:Trebuchet MS;margin-left:40px">HALLIBURTON</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="s1">
                        <img src="img/schlumberger.png" style="width:100px;height:45px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="s1">
                        <img src="img/Khalda.png" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
                    </div>

                    <div class="s1">
                        <img src="img/weatherford.png" style="width:100px;height:35px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="s1">
                        <img src="img/suco.png" style="width:120px;height:45px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="s1">
                        <img src="img/midor.png" style="width:60px;height:60px;margin-top:-10px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="s1">
                        <img src="img/Baker Hughes.png" style="width:90px;height:45px">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </footer>
  

  </section>


</body>
</html>
```